# EFCore 2.2 TPT without abstract base class

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

I'm trying to create a scheme where EF uses TPT (multiple tables, no discriminator) buth **without** using an **abstract** base class. The base class itself should be useable and the inherited class should only extend this one, eg:

```
public class Invoice {
 //Some invoice properties
}

public class ExtendedInvoice : Invoice {
 //Some extended properties
}
```

As soon as I mark Invoice abstract it works but any invoice needs to be an "Extended" one. Is that scenario I described somehow possible? I'm pretty sure I've done it with the "old" EntityFramework.

[tpt-inheritance-with-non-abstract-base-class-in-code-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202178/tpt-inheritance-with-non-abstract-base-class-in-code-first) does not answer my question since InternalTask and ExternalTask do not inheritate from Task (only TaskBase, they need to be castable and I don't want an extra table for the *regular* invoice).

Comment: Currently EF Core supports *only* TPH, so discussing TPT (with or without abstract base class) makes no sense.

Comment: Ok, it seams to work with abstract classes - but what I want is not supported with EF Core 2.2. Going with this solution for now:

https://weblogs.thinktecture.com/pawel/2018/05/entity-framework-core-inheritance-tpt-is-not-supported-is-it-part-1-code-first.html